# Going through minimized windows in Ubuntu dock

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, minimize

I've been using Elementary OS for years, and now I am back to Ubuntu 18.04.

In such a distro there is a very useful function, which is that if one has several minimized windows of the same software (e.g. several PDFs documents) one can show them one by one via scrolling in the dock icon (moving the mouse wheel or moving two fingers on the touchpad).

The function doesn't work in Ubuntu. Is there any way to make it work? And if not, is there a less cumbersome way to go through the minimized windows than right click -> All the windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Ubuntu dock is based upon the Dash-to-Dock extension and uses the same dconf preference schemas/keys.

The key you are looking to change is called `scroll-action` and has three options:

- `do-nothing` - No action when scrolling on an application icon
- `cycle-windows` - Cycle between open windows of this application
- `switch-workspace` - Moves the application between workspaces (***default***)

You can change this preference by running this command at a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'OPTION'
```

In your case, you should run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'cycle-windows'
```